# Function (trigger) to insert rows based on interval and duration

Tags: postgresql

I have a `schedule` table, like so:

```
ScheduleId::uuid | Start::timestamptz(now()) | SlotSize::int(minutes) | Interval::int(days)
```

and a `slot` table like so:

```
SlotId::uuid | ScheduleId::uuid | Start::timestamptz | End::timestamptz
```

I want to automatically insert slots, based on a trigger on the schedule table.

So far I have:

```
create
    trigger create_slots after insert
        on
        schedule for each row execute procedure create_new_slots();

create or replace function create_new_slots() 
returns trigger 
language plpgsql 
as $function$ 
  begin
-- in a loop determine how many slots there are, then insert each one
    insert into slot
      select
        uuid_generate_v4(),
        new."ScheduleId",
        start, -- need to determine the start time of each instance of slot
        end -- need to determine the end time of each instance of slot
-- end loop
  end return new;
end $function$
```

I need to somehow put this into a cursor and calculate the number of slots and the start and end times each slot.

I am using PostgreSQL 10

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: looks simple - please add sample data. best if you build it in db-fiddle or such

Comment: That is syntactically incorrect PL/pgSQL. It is hard to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so what I needed, it seems, was to generate a series based on the [Start] time (rounded to the hour), the end time (which is the [Start] time + the [PlanningHorizon] in days) and the [SlotSize]. Then loop through this series and insert each time slot into my [Slot] table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_new_slots()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    slot timestamptz;
begin
    for slot in select generate_series(
        date_trunc('hour', new."Start")::timestamptz, 
        (new."Start" + interval '1' day * new."PlanningHorizon")::timestamptz,
        new."SlotSize" * '1 minutes'::interval)
    loop
        insert into slot select uuid_generate_v4(), new."ScheduleId", slot, slot + new."SlotSize" * '1 minutes'::interval;
    end loop;
return NEW;
end
$function$
```